# mouseleave not triggered when move mouse slowly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If you put a mouseleave listener on a div at the very top of the page, it will not fire on Chrome if you move the mouse slowly out of the top of the page (but it does work if you do it quickly). It's the same if you listen for the event on the document or body. Works fine in Firefox.

You can see the problem in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/jackocnr/full/vzdtr). Uncomment the CSS padding to see my current workaround.

Any thoughts on why this is the case? Possibly a Webkit bug? Any other workarounds?

Update: this not related to jQuery - I reproduced the problem using the native mouseleave JavaScript event in Chrome.

Update: filed a Chromium issue: [mouseleave not fired when move mouse slowly](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=333959)

Comment: Works fine in Safari for me

Comment: This happen to me only in your codeopen when the layouy is "view is bottom", if I change the layout there to "view to the side" it works good. have you tried this not in codeopen? the demo in Lquery works good for me for example

Comment: @Noampz that's interesting. Yes I have tried this not on codepen - I have the problem on my live site. Can you confirm what you get when you try it in "full" mode? Link: http://codepen.io/jackocnr/full/wsoBj

Comment: I filed a bug with jQuery, but may well be a Webkit issue. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14616

Comment: Update: it's not a jQuery issue - see the updated codepen. So it's just a problem with Chrome? Not sure where to file a bug.

Comment: Same issue in firefox

Answer (score 1):

The codepen page in full mode works fine for me, counter increases also with slow movements. I tested it on Windows 7 with Chrome 31.0.

Comment: For me it varies how slow you have to move the mouse to see the problem, but I consistently see it when I move it as slow as I possibly can e.g. 1 pixel per second. I'm using Chrome 31 on OSX 10.9